# Please vote to undelete this question

Tags: support, specific-question, vote-to-undelete

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67711633/deal-with-a-temporary-directory-deletion-in-a-flask-app) was edited a short while before it got deleted by the system as an abandoned questions, and I think it deserves to exist. It is a duplicate, I know, but I know that I put a nice amount of effort in to it as well as [MisterMiyagi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5349916/mistermiyagi) editing it. I would like to have it get a chance for upvotes. I saw in the comments that some of you believe it doesn't stand a chance, as well as in the answers, but I think there is no way of knowing that for sure until it can actually receive votes and answers again.

Comment: *"I would like it undeleted so that maybe some of the downvotes can be reversed."* This is not a very compelling rationale for undeletion. You have made an edit to the post, but it's an extremely trivial one. Why, exactly, do you think the reception will be different now? What value do you think the question offers? Why should we consider undeleting it? These are the kinds of things you should discuss in this request (and the lack of them is why this request is getting downvoted).

Comment: @codyGray, and edit (a very good one) has been made to this question a short while before it was deleted. The last edit made to was only to get it into the review queus.

Comment: I don't expect the post being undeleted to result in it being upvoted. It's a sign post, links to it for most users will just redirect to the duplicate target.

Comment: @KevinB, it can't get upvoted when it's deleted. Whatever chances it does have, will only apply if it can be.

Comment: @ThunderCoder the thing is... unless you get a positive meta effect response, that's... not gonna happen. And given that the previous meta effect response on that post resulted in 8 downvotes... it's not looking like a good move IMO.

Comment: @KevinB, that was before it got edited. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67711633/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries

Comment: The post existed, undeleted, for 10 days after that edit and received +1 -2

Comment: @KevinB it didn't get enough views for something to happen to it, in my opinion, being nearly a month old by then. Not that I can prove it or anything, but still...

Answer (score 14):

The question was closed as a dupe, then the system automatically deleted it.

Not seeing much point in *un*deleting this question, since it'd still have to prove that it wasn't a dupe or somehow clean itself up to be a better sign post, and I'm not seeing a lot of opportunity for that.